# Prevent multiple users from running the same SQL Server stored procedure at the same time

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to prevent multiple users from updating a table at the same time.

In the database `"abc"` update is required on table `"abd.dbo.xyz"`. I wrote code which is not yet fulfilling my requirements.

Any help?

```
use [abc]
BEGIN TRANSACTION 
DECLARE @res INT
EXEC @res = sp_getapplock
@Resource = 'This a Lock ID',
@LockMode = 'Exclusive',
@LockOwner = 'Transaction',
@LockTimeout = 15000,
        
IF @res NOT IN (0, 1)
BEGIN
    RAISERROR ( 'Unable to acquire Lock', 16, 1 )
END
ELSE
BEGIN

-- this is update command which i need to run one instance only
Update abc.dbo.xyz set IsKeyProduct= NULL Where IsKeyProduct is not NULL;

EXEC @res = sp_releaseapplock
@Resource = 'This a Lock ID', 
@DbPrincipal = 'public', 
@LockOwner = 'Transaction'

END 
COMMIT
```

Comment: You may be doing more work than necessary.  Review table hints and see if they do what you want:  https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187373(v=sql.105).aspx.

Comment: What is the reason for this? The DBMS handles this.

Comment: Instead of update command i have a stored proc which takes around 60min to finish. In the same time if any other user run the same proc then it takes to much time to complete (90min). So i want to avoid this issue.

Comment: `sp_getapplock` should do what you want. Check the docs what parameters it has and what it returns when it acquires the lock successfully or fails. I think result `>= 0` means that it acquired the lock successfully.

Comment: You have a transaction start and commit. No need for anything else.

Answer (score 2):

You are checking if the result is in (0,1), while 1 means that the procedure had to wait for the lock to be released. If you check for only (0), it means that the lock was granted immediately (so no other instance of the proc was runnig)

Easiest way is to use *sp_getapplock* in your stored procedure.

```
Exec @lokcResult =sp_getapplock @Resource='MyLock', @LockMode='Exclusive', @LockOwner='Transaction', @LockTimeout = 500
```

After you shuold check `@lockResult`, and if it is not equal to 0, you should return without doing anything.
See getapplock documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189823.aspx

`@LockOwner='Transaction'` tells to hold the lock as long as the transaction is running, so you dont actually need to bother with releasing the lock