# Is exec stored procedure synchronous?

Tags: sql-server, database

We have a micro-service architecture. We have a stored procedure (e.g. `prc_test_sproc`) for a given database

Service 1 calls `prc_test_sproc` like this:

```
exec prc_test_sproc
```

and at the same time, Service 2 also calls `exec prc_test_sproc`.

How to ensure that Service 2 doesn't get lock of `prc_test_sproc` before Service 1 completes execution of `prc_test_sproc` for a given database?

extract from stored procedure looks like this

```
DECLARE @command NVARCHAR(256) = 'kill ' + cast(@SPID AS NVARCHAR(5))
EXEC(@command)
```

Micro service may be using same user

This is for Microsoft SQL Server.

Comment: Locks are table based, not SP based... And like all good databases are designed to allow as much concurrent operation as possible while maintaining ACID.

Comment: @DaleK , is there any way I can make the call to SProc synchronous?

Comment: Do you really need to? That is pretty much an anti-pattern? If you design your SP correctly it should be able to handle concurrent operation.

Comment: Actually the Sproc kills a session and sessions gets re-used quickly. I want to ensure that there aren't any race conditions where wrong session gets killed

Comment: You can force single user using `sp_getapplock`

Comment: @DaleK SProc looks like this

 ```DECLARE @command NVARCHAR(256) = 'kill ' + cast(@SPID AS NVARCHAR(5))
EXEC(@command)```

Comment: [Edit] that into your question

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prevent multiple users from running the same SQL Server stored procedure at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36198280/prevent-multiple-users-from-running-the-same-sql-server-stored-procedure-at-the)

Comment: Microservice may be using same user.

Comment: Thats not what is means... read the answer.